# How to find which variations city names are used in daily speech?

Tags: word-choice, idiomaticity

The Wikipedia page for [Staaten der Erde](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Staaten_der_Erde) contains a couple of options for the names of some capitals. Since I’m not a native German speaker, I wonder how I can find out, which of the options are most common in daily use, for example:

- Zagreb or Agram?
- Vilnius or Wilna?
- Bratislava or Pressburg?
- Ljubljana or Laibach?

I’m working on a country/capital quiz app, so I need to choose the ones that German-speaking people would feel familiar with.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. I made your question a little bit more general, as otherwise you would technically have to ask a question for each capital. As the answer is still valid and helpful to you, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run an N-gram for each pair, these are the results:

In the actuality, as used in (scanned) books:

> 1. Agram < Zagreb
> 2. Wilna > Vilnius (the trend being, apparently, that *Vilnius* replaces *Wilna*)
> 3. Laibach < Ljubljana
> 4. Pressburg < Bratislava

Except the pair of names for the capital of Lithuania, the original name is much more used nowadays, while their "German version" dominated till the beginnings of the XXth century.

Comment: I wasn’t aware of _Agram_ before, at all.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way: If you google for Agram, the Wikipedia-page that shows up is not really useful. But two places below Zagreb shows up. You can also open the English Wiki page and click on German/Deutsch on the left side where it says "Languages".

My impression is that the modern Germans try to use the native name of cities or persons as much as possible, while older people still hang on to the "German" names.

Comment: I re-added the information to the Wikipedia article, which a careless editor who never heard of _Agram_ before (understandably) and didn’t bother to check had simply removed. – Regarding the second paragraph of your answer, I don’t think it’s that simple. There is no tendency to say _Roma_ instead of _Rom_, or _Milano_ and _Venezia_ instead of _Mailand_ and _Venedig_. It’s rather that certain parts of Europe once belonged to German-speaking countries (Germany and Austria) and/or had a considerable German-speaking population who used German names, and this is no longer the case.

Comment: In the special case of places being renamed after e.g. WWII, the choice depends on whether we are talking in a historical or contemporary context.

Comment: @chirlu you are right, good examples.

Comment: To add on @chirlu ’s comment: we also say *Tokio, Peking* and most notably *Moskau* (even though that last one was definitely affected by the last war Germany waged).